# Symfony redirecting but i can not find the cookie

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony, I am trying to pass the JWT object into the Cookie method and everything looks fine except that I don't think that it is logging me in. I have echoed a message to see if I am logged in then it should echo Logged in. I am able to redirect to the index page but the message does not show that I am logged in.

my doLogin.php looks like bellow

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../inc/bootstrap.php';

$user = findUserByEmail(request()->get('email'));
if(empty($user)){
    redirect('login.php');
}

if(!password_verify( request()->get('password'), $user['password'])){
    redirect('login.php');
}


$expTime = time() + 3600;

$jwt = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode( //header
    [
        'iss' => request()->getBaseUrl(), // who issued this claim, here will localhost
        'sub' => "{$user['id']}", //who is the subject
        'exp' => $expTime, 
        'iat' => time(), //issued at
        'nbf' => time(), // not before
        'is_admin' => $user['role_id'] == 1
    ],
    getenv("SECRET_KEY"), //payload
    'HS256');// signature 

    $accessToken = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie('access_token', $jwt, $expTime, '../', getenv("COOKIE_DOMAIN"));
    //var_dump($accessToken);
    redirect('../index.php', ['cookies' => [$accessToken]]);
```

my redirect function looks like the following

```
function redirect($path, $extra = []){

$response= \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::Create(null, \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_FOUND, ['Location' => $path]);
if(key_exists('cookies', $extra)){
    foreach($extra['cookies'] as $cookie){
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookie); 
    }
}
$response->send();
exit;
}
```

The file below is my index.php page.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/head.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/nav.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/bootstrap.php';
//echo __DIR__ .'/inc';

?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
        <h2>Book Voting System</h2>
        <?php 
            if(request()->cookies->has('access_token')){
            echo "logged in";
            }
        ?>

        <p>Welcome to the book voting system.  Use this system to submit books you like and see if others like them as well
        by letting them upvote it.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/footer.php';
```

Can someone tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: index.php

login.php

inc(folder)->
      | function.php 
      | bootstrap.php
     
procedures(folder)->
      |doLogin.php

Comment: The above is my directory structure